# Easiest way to copy big database on same SQL instance

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-administration

What is the easiest and safe way to copy a big database on same instance of SQL Server? 'Copy Database' wizard or Backup and Restore option? Or anything better?

Comment: I used to use Back Up database and then Restore it (these options are available from SSMS) Task context menu on database. I think copy database is the same operation but compressed to one option. Big databases have this feature, that they are time consuming in managing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will go for copy database option.

Comment: I have found that copy fails a bit so I use backup / restore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One more solution is to detach database, copy database files to desired location and then attach new files as new database.